# Find, copy, move selection using Word VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I've tried this every which way and it still goes past the End bookmark.

```
Sub Macro3() 
    Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range 
    Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Range 
    Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("END").Range 
    Selection.SetRange rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End 
    Do 
        If Selection.Find.Found And Selection.Range.Start < rngEnd.End Then 'do your copy/moves ... 
        Else 
            Exit Sub 
        End If 
    Loop 
End Sub
```

I have a document that has recurring information I need to find and copy/move to the end of the document.  I don't want it to search through what has been sent to the bottom of the document.  I've used the following code; however, it doesn't stop running once it reaches the END bookmark. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

    Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range
    Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Range
    Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("END").Range

    Selection.SetRange rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Forward = True
            .Execute FindText:="Flag"
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            .Forward = False
            .Execute FindText:="IDR Date"
        End With
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        Selection.TypeBackspace
        Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
            .Forward = True
            .Execute FindText:="Flag"
        End With
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

        If Selection.Find.Found Then
            With Selection.Find
                .Forward = True
                .Execute FindText:="Flag"
                Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
                .Forward = False
                .Execute FindText:="IDR Date"
            End With
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
            Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
            Selection.TypeBackspace
            Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            With Selection.Find
                .Forward = True
                .Execute FindText:="Flag"
            End With
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Cut
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
            Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this every which way and it still goes past the End bookmark. Sub Macro3() Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Range Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("END").Range Selection.SetRange rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End Do If Selection.Find.Found And Selection.Range.Start < rngEnd.End Then 'do your copy/moves ... Else Exit Sub End If Loop End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not going to stop running when the "End" bookmark is reached because you do not have any test for it. After each:

```
If Selection.Find.Found then
```

You need to check the starting location of the Found string against the End location of the End bookmark, which would look something like:

```
If Selection.Find.Found and Selection.Range.Start < rngEnd.End then
       'do your copy/moves
   else
       Exit Sub
End If
```